# What is the alternative in Harmony OS for function setBackgroundColor() on View class in Android?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am working on a HarmonyOS project in that I wanted to set the background color of the component. In Android we have a function `setBackgroundColor()` in the View class, this can be done as shown below.

```
View titleLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.titleLayout);
titleLayout.setBackgroundColor(calendarTitleBackgroundColor);
```

How can I set background color to a component in HarmonyOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to build an Element using some color,

```java
    public static Element buildElementByColor(int color) {
        ShapeElement drawable = new ShapeElement();
        drawable.setShape(ShapeElement.RECTANGLE);
        drawable.setRgbColor(RgbColor.fromArgbInt(color));
        return drawable;
    }
```

later you have set the built element using setBackground API

```java
    component.setBackground(buildElementByColor((Color.DKGRAY).getValue()));
```

Answer (score 1):

@[Gowtham GS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10472898/gowtham-gs)'s answer is  correct. I'd like to add a little more:

You can also define the background color of the component when defining the component in the XML file. The attribute is `background_element`.

For example: `ohos:background_element="white"`